# Error while trying to get data from table

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, typescript

'// Issue: Not able to fetch data from table.

// My Code

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    server: "test.database.windows.net",
    user: "username",
    password: "password",
    database: 'database',
    port: 1433,
})
.connect()
  .then((pool: any) => {
    console.log('Connected to MSSQL')
    return pool
  })
  .catch((err: any) => console.log('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config: ', err))
;

describe('any test', () => {

    it('verification', async () => {

        try
        {
            const pool = await poolPromise;

            const result = await pool.request()
            .query('select * from table where username = "Protractor"');

            console.log(result);
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });     
});
```

**Error Occurred**:

[13:20:25] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:20:25] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Started
Connected to MSSQL
{ RequestError: Invalid column name 'Protractor'.
at handleError (C:\Users\automation\node_modules\mssql\lib\msnodesqlv8\request.js:258:21)
at StreamEvents.emit (events.js:189:13)
at errors.forEach.err (C:\Users\automation\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\reader.js:37:20)
at Array.forEach ()
at routeStatementError (C:\Users\automation\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\reader.js:30:14)
at invokeObject.end (C:\Users\automation\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\reader.js:209:11)
at freeStatement (C:\Users\automation\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\driver.js:183:13)
at cppDriver.freeStatement (C:\Users\automation\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\driver.js:163:13)  originalError:
{ Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Protractor'. sqlstate: '42S22', code: 207 },
name: 'RequestError',
number: 207,
state: '42S22' }

Comment: Your table has no column named `username`.

Comment: yeah, table have column named username. If i am trying the same query in SSMS, it is working fine, but when using with javascript code, it shows the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double and single quotes are not interchangeable in T-SQL.

Try this instead:

```
const result = await pool.request()
        .query(`select * from table where username = 'Protractor'`);
```

or this:

```
const result = await pool.request()
        .query('select * from table where username = \'Protractor\'');
```